# How do I get these toilet shut off valve out?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, pipe, removal, valve

As title says I am trying to figure out how to remove the old shut off valve from the pipe. I've been watching lot of videos, reading up on articles and all seem to deal with compression fit type but what I have at work (1<sup>st</sup> photo) and home (2<sup>nd</sup> photo) seem different from what I am dealing with. (Top photo is just a reference)

[image]
[image]

It doesn't look like it is soldered on either (at least that's what I think)

Comment: Thank you Niall C. for pasting photos directly from the link :) Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the valve solders to the 1/2 inch water source pipe. the outlet is a pretty standard 3/8" compression fitting.  It is a little hard to tell from your pics, but it is rare that the valve would be a threaded fitting to the water source, but not unheard of. The differences between the valves pictured are that the top pic is a 90 degree 1/4 turn valve and the bottom pic is a straight multi-turn valve. If you are going to replace them, do yourself a favor and use nothing less than a  1/4 turn stainless steel ball valve. They are available in both straight and 90 degree styles.

Assuming they are solder on, you must heat them to melt the solder and remove them, or cut them free with a tubing cutter as close to the existing valve as possible.  If you unsolder them, take great care to remove all the old solder and clean/smooth the pipe end well before attempting to solder a new valve on. A basic knowledge of sweating pipes is needed for this project as well as basic plumbing tools like a tubing cutter, torch, abrasive cloth, flux and solder.

Comment: Take it from an idiot, soldering valves to pipes is not idiot proof. There's a good chance you'll either have a cold soldered joint (leak) or ruin the valve seals, or both, unless you're experienced in this stuff. You're better off soldering a pipe thread adapter on and using a PTxComp ball valve. And remove as much water as you can from the pipe or it will never get hot enough.

Comment: As the first reply suggest, I think it will make it easier for me if I just cut the pipe instead of trying to heat it and remove it. Trust me you dont want to see me with a torch lol

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is soldered.  You can either resolder on another valve or use a compression valve.  I use compression valves for shut-offs and just installed this one.

If it isn't soldered then then the nut closest to the wall turns out and there is a pin under it.  You have to take the pin out to release the compression valve - if it were a sharkbite or similar you would need to buy a little horseshoe device to release it.  With the water off.

[Example of compression valve](http://www.lowes.com/pd_271778-143-K2622PCLF_0__?productId=3151811&Ntt=compression%20angle%20stop%20valve&pl=1&currentURL=?Ntt=compression%2bangle%2bstop%2bvalve&facetInfo=) - every store has there own brands for these.  Also in most stores they are not with plumbing they are with toilet parts.

Make sure you get the right size.  Looks like yours is 1/2 to 3/8.

This is a 10 minute job!

To install - 
- shut off water
- cut copper as close to current shut-off as possible.
- clean inside and outside of copper
- slide compression fitting on
- connect toilet
- turn on water
- turn valve on and off to make sure there are no leaks

Tools needed

- [Pipe cleaning brush](http://www.lowes.com/pd_14846-72906-LX-00088_4294822079__?productId=3130863&Ns=p_product_qty_sales_dollar%7C1)
- [Tube Cutter](http://www.lowes.com/pd_331920-943-36878.UPP5_0__?productId=3234673&Ntt=copper%20cutter&pl=1&currentURL=?Ntt=copper%2bcutter&facetInfo=)

Comment: Compression fittings are measured in OD, so you need a 5/8" OD compression fitting for a 1/2" pipe

Comment: I am not a plumber but just a DIYer with a lot of plumbing experience.  I have installed at least 30-40 shut-off valves over the past few years.  If I had 1/2 inch copper I always got what was labeled as a 1/2 compression fitting - either the one at lowes in my answer or a similar manufacturer (yellow and blue box) from HD.  Most toilets I have done had 1/4 inch going in though but this looks like 3/8.

Comment: weird I wonder if there is something regional about it or maybe just how they label them.  the first time I went looking for them I couldn't figure out why I couldn't find any 1/2" ones at HD - labeled as 5/8 instead

Comment: Hmm thanks for your input. The funny thing is I dont know whether the white crusted stuff on the pipe is mineral deposit because it doesnt look like copper lol. It is indeed 1/2 inch to 3/8.

Comment: Looks like copper to me.  Scrub it with a steel/wool brush for a minute and you should see some copper.

Comment: Cool thanks. I feel lazy though cause jobs complete (well almost cause I want to change the valve too)

Comment: No plumbing job is a 10 minute job. :) (Or I just suck at plumbing.)

Comment: This is a true 10 min job - given that you have tube cutter, brush, and the right valve.  Those are big givens though!  And if you have done it before it is a 4-5 min job.  Also with compression make sure that you have at least 1.5 inches clearance from the wall and if you lose a half inch from cutting out the soldered connection that your toilet line still will make it (usually not an issue).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both ends just screw on.

Turn off the house water, unscrew both ends, take it with you to get the replacement (or make several trips like me).

Comment: Very unlikely.  99% it is soldered. If it were threaded, you would expect the valve to have flat sides so you could use a wrench

Comment: Are you talking about the flexible hose?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your input guys!

While waiting for replies I did further digging and eventually figured out that it was soldered on.

So I decided to bypass changing the shut off valve since it still works even though it looks like crap and I needed a new toilet lol. Perhaps I will tackle it very soon :) I think I will end up cutting it to put new compression type shut off valve. Sharkbite ball valve looks nice and simple enough.

Took me roughly 2 hours to complete the job including a trip to hardware store to get one more wax ring to stack it to make tight contact. First time and bit nervous but all in all wasnt difficult. Wish the bowl was lighter though haha.

Gonna do one more toilet tomorrow and next project is bathroom sink!

Cheers,

Charles
[image: Finished!]